# Java выпадает элемент <List>

Tags: java, объекты, java-hashmap

Добрый день.
Есть хеш объектов вида:

```
HashMap <String, Question> hashQuestionAnswers = new HashMap<String, Question>();
```

Введён для обеспечения уникальности, на случай совпадения объектов.
Сам класс выглядит так:

```
public class Question extends BaseNode implements BaseInternalElementsNode{ 
    private String text;
    private List<Answer> answers;
```

Родительский класс имеет следующие важные поля:

```
public abstract class BaseNode {
    private String idNode; // определяем имя ID элемента и его значение.
    private String nodeName; // определяем имя ноды <nodeName ...>
```

Методы интерфейса не принципиальны - они направлены на работу с XML-кой.

Класс Answer :

```
public class Answer {
    private String id;
    private String text;
```

Собственно, для ключа hashQuestionAnswers используется idNode родительского класса BaseNode (он сделан уникальным).
Собственно в чём проблема. Поочерёдно перебирая объекты Question двух списков столкнулся с проблемой, что в какой-то момент похожие(не одинаковые!) замещают друг-друга. Из-за чего вся работа идёт на смарку.
Вот участок кода, который описывает этот момент:

```
Question resultQuestion = exam.checkQuestionWithAnswer();
if (resultQuestion!=null){
    addLineToConsole("Add to hashQuestionAnswers question id: " + resultQuestion.getIdNode() + ". " + resultQuestion.getText());
    addLineToConsole("First answer id: " + resultQuestion.getAnswers().get(0).getId() + ". " + resultQuestion.getAnswers().get(0).getText());
    addLineToConsole("Add to hashQuestionAnswers question id: " + resultQuestion.getIdNode());

    hashQuestionAnswers.put(resultQuestion.getIdNode(), resultQuestion);
    addLineToConsole("............................\nCheck hashQuestionAnswers{}...");
    checkHashQuestionsResultWA(hashQuestionAnswers);
    addLineToConsole("............................\n");

    unknownQuestion=false;
}
```

Что было понятно приведу лог, который выводит addLineToConsole() при добавлении в хэшмап нового объекта. Сразу скажу, что объекты полностью совпадают кроме nodeId и у вложенных списков Answer отличается id

первый объект

```
............................ Check hashQuestionAnswers{}... size hashMapQuestions: 1
---------------------CHECK HM--------------------- 
Question: q1 (q1). text1
 - answer: q1_1. answer1
--------------------- FINISH --------------------- 
............................
```

Появляется второй объект

```
............................ Check hashQuestionAnswers{}... size hashMapQuestions: 2
---------------------CHECK HM--------------------- 
Question: q1 (q1). text1
 - answer: q1_1. answer1 
Question: q2 (q2). text2
 - answer: q2_2. answer2
--------------------- FINISH ---------------------

............................
```

Третий объект

```
............................ Check hashQuestionAnswers{}... size hashMapQuestions: 3
---------------------CHECK HM--------------------- 
Question: q1 (q1). text1
 - answer: q1_1. answer1 
Question: q2 (q29). text29 similar as text2
 - answer: c29_2. answer29 similar as answer2 
Question: q29 (q29). text29 similar as text2
 - answer: q29_2. answer29 similar as answer2
--------------------- FINISH ---------------------

............................
```

Четвёртый объект

```
............................ Check hashQuestionAnswers{}... size hashMapQuestions: 4
---------------------CHECK HM--------------------- 
Question: q1 (q1). text1
 - answer: q1_1. answer1 
Question: q2 (q29). text29 similar as text2
 - answer: q29_2. answer29 similar as answer2 
Question: q29 (q29). text29 similar as text2
 - answer: q29_2. answer29 similar as answer2 
Question: q30 (q30). text30
 - answer: q30_1. answer30
--------------------- FINISH --------------------- 
............................
```

Т.е. как видите, при добавлении похожего объекта, происходит замещение более раннего объекта на него. Они могут идти как друг за дружкой, так и на дистанции в сотню объектов. Порядок не принципиален.
Никак не могу понять, почему q29 подменяет q2 если они не равны, не одинаковы. List тоже не спасает - там такая же ошибка лезет.
Можете объяснить, почему? Ошибка где-то на поверхности, но я не могу её увидеть.

Comment: методы hashCode() и equals() переопределены?

Comment: нет. Хммм. Надо порыть

Comment: При записи в мапу сначала вычисляется хэш код ключа. На основе хэш кода ключа определяется, в какое место положить объект. Если в этом месте уже что-то лежит, то эти ключи сравниваются при помощи equals. Если equals дает true, то элемент перезаписывается новым

Comment: да я в эту сторону смотрел, но решил, что проскочу, так как вложенные объекты (List<Answers>) отличаются. Но увы. Переписал методы - не помогло (ниже результат теста, который завершился успешно)

Answer (score 0):

описал методы hashCode() и equals()
Прогнал тест:

```
public void testHash(){
        Question question1 = new Question();
        question1.setText("qwe");
        question1.setIdNode("q1");
        System.out.println(question1.hashCode());
        Question question2 = new Question();
        question2.setText("qwe");
        question2.setIdNode("q2");
        System.out.println(question2.hashCode());

        HashMap<String, Question> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Question>();
        hashMap.put(question1.getIdNode(), question1);
        hashMap.put(question2.getIdNode(), question2);

        assertNotSame(hashMap.get(question1.getIdNode()),hashMap.get(question2.getIdNode()));
        //assertNotSame(question,question2);
        List<String> listKey = new ArrayList(hashMap.keySet());
        Collections.sort(listKey);
        for(String key: listKey){
            //for(Map.Entry<String, Question> entry : hashMapQuestions.entrySet()){
            Question question = hashMap.get(key);
            System.out.println("Question: " + key + " ("+ question.getIdNode() + "). " +  question.getText());
            for(Answer answer: question.getAnswers()){
                System.out.println(" - answer: "+ answer.getId() + ". " + answer.getText());
            }
        }

    }
```

тест идёт нормально, а картинка не менятется :( 
причём используется тот же код для вывода содержимого HashMap

Вот вывод теста:

```
3487426
3487427
Question: q1 (q1). qwe
Question: q2 (q2). qwe
```

UPD: если убрать переписанные методы hashCode() и equals(), то ничего не изменится, тест успешно будет идти.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблему решил, но сути не понял.
Пришлось дополнительно создавать ещё один новый объект перед записью в хэш.

```
if (resultQuestion!=null){
    Question question = new Question();
    question.setIdNode(resultQuestion.getIdNode());
    question.setText(resultQuestion.getText());
    question.setAnswers(resultQuestion.getAnswers());
    resultQuestion.hashCode();

    hashQuestionAnswers.put(question.getIdNode(), question);
    addLineToConsole("............................\nCheck hashQuestionAnswers{}...");
    checkHashQuestionsResultWA(hashQuestionAnswers);
    addLineToConsole("............................\n");
    resultQuestion=null;

}
```

на сию мысль натолкнул юнит-тест
Теперь замена ушла.